# What does "hit someone on the roll" here mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, expressions

> Two possessions later, and still trailing by 1, the Bucks set up in the same alignment, only this time Donte DiVincenzo had the ball. Antetokounmpo delivered another screen, and DiVincenzo dropped a soft floater through the net. The next time down the floor, the Bucks went back to Middleton, with Antetokounmpo once again setting the pick. **Middleton hit Antetokounmpo on the roll.**

Does the last sentence mean Middleton passed to Antetokounmpo to score?

Comment: Wow! I thought I knew English, but pretty much the entirety of OP's cited cited might as well be in a foreign language for all I can understand! This isn't really about learning English - it's about learning *very* obscure domain-specific terminology. Which a non-native speaker should be able to "research" just as well as me (perhaps *more* easily, since presumably anyone who wants to know such things already knows much more about basketball than me).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The roll* is a part of an offensive play in basketball called ["pick and roll"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick_and_roll) where the screener moves toward the basket (=rolls) to receive a pass.

Have a look at [this lesson](https://youtu.be/ffjo8ReDzhA?t=129) (the roll starts at 2:09).